# Extending the default OpenLayers edit style?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a vector style, with a larger `image: radius`. I would like to have the select interaction's style match the vector style's `image: radius`.

How can I do so without manually redefining the whole editing style based on [this page in the documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.html)?

Is it possible to take the default style and override only one part? Like the image's radius? Or at least redefine only the whole image?

Comment: Let me know if the given answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/w6dv55Ln/)**.

---

Share a [style function](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction) between `ol.layer.Vector` and `ol.interaction.Select` and when selecting, change a variable that will be read within your function:

```
var radius = 10;
var styleFunction = function() {
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: radius,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'green'
        })
      })
    })
  ];
};

var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  style: styleFunction
});

select_interaction.on('select', function(evt) {
  radius = evt.selected.length > 0 ? 20 : 10;
});
```

[I'm proposing](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5748) a `ol.style.Circle#setRadius` that could be used in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm looking for the opposite direction. That is:
unselected style: orange lines, orange polygons, orange circles with radius 10
selected style: blue-white lines, blue-white polygons, blue-white cirlcles with radius 10 (not 6 or 8 as with default selection mode).

Blue-white refers to the default select style.

Comment: @zsero It does matter the style you will set, I've just put you on the right way - that is share a style function.

Comment: OK, but how can I access the default blue-white style? That is the one on this page: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.html